# Selenium Webdriver for Mobile testing

Tags: iphone, mobile, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm getting the following error

> ERROR running Appium command: Cannot call method 'send' of null

while running my selelnium test on iPhones. The same works on Android. What could be the potential issue? any help is appreciated.

The code that throws the error is :

```
  public static boolean focusWindowByHandle(int inWindowIndex)
  {
    boolean blResult = false;
    try
    {
      Object[] arrWindowHandles = GenericKeyword.driver.getWindowHandles().toArray();
      if (inWindowIndex <= arrWindowHandles.length - 1) {
        String strWindowHandle = GenericKeyword.driver.getWindowHandles().toArray()[inWindowIndex].toString();
        GenericKeyword.driver.switchTo().window(strWindowHandle);
        blResult = true;
```

Comment: modified the question as per the rules.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as a comment but I am posting it in this section owing to the readability.

Can you check if your version of 'appium.js' has the exact snippet as below?

```
logger.info('Shutting down appium session...');
   if (this.isSafariLauncherApp === true) {
     this.device.leaveWebView(function() {
      if (this.device.udid === null) {
      if (this.device.udid === null && this.device.instruments !== null) {
         this.device.instruments.shutdown(function() {
           this.cleanupSession(null, cb);
         }.bind(this));
```